# Prisma - Connect to an external database

Tags: database, docker, prisma

Prisma is using the database setup by docker and it is working fine. I want to use another database like AWS RDS. 
im using this doc: https://www.prisma.io/docs/tutorials/setup-prisma/connect-empty-db/mysql-dusee0nore

Here you have my file before:

docker-compose.yml (before)

```
version: '3'
services:
  prisma:
    image: prismagraphql/prisma:1.8
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '4466:4466'
    environment:
      PRISMA_CONFIG: |
        port: 4466
        # uncomment the next line and provide the env var PRISMA_MANAGEMENT_API_SECRET=my-secret to activate cluster security
        # managementApiSecret: my-secret
        databases:
          default:
            connector: mysql
            host: mysql
            port: 3306
            user: root
            password: prisma
            migrations: true
  mysql:
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: prisma
      TZ: America/Los_Angeles
    volumes:
      - mysql:/var/lib/mysql
volumes:
  mysql:
```

docker-compose.yml (After)

```
version: '3'
services:
  prisma:
    image: prismagraphql/prisma:1.8
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '4466:4466'
    environment:
      PRISMA_CONFIG: |
        port: 4466
        # uncomment the next line and provide the env var PRISMA_MANAGEMENT_API_SECRET=my-secret to activate cluster security
        # managementApiSecret: my-secret
        databases:
          default:
            connector: mysql
            host: *************.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com
            user: *************
            password: *************
            rawAccess: true
            port: '3306'
            migrations: false
```

The fields host, user and password are good as I am able to connect to this database with others tools.

then:

```
> docker-compose up -d
> Recreating server_prisma_1 ... done
```

After starting the server, I got:

`[Network error]: FetchError: request to http://localhost:4466/nacho/prod failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:4466`

or

`[Network error]: FetchError: request to http://localhost:4466/nacho/prod failed, reason: socket hang up`

Any idea how can I debug this?

Comment: Is the container actually starting up, or is it crashing immediately?  `docker-compose logs prisma` or running `docker-compose up` without `-d` should tell you a little more.  (I am suspicious of the string vs. integer `port:`.)

Comment: For more extensive logs you can view the raw logs from the running Docker containers with `docker-compose logs`. Did you run `prisma deploy` after changing the database? Did it work?